# Calculating Running Avg for YTD Sum with constant denominator for a year

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following table from SQL

```
ID      Date         Score
-----+-------------+---------- 
10     2015-01-10      5
20     2015-01-10      5
10     2015-02-10      15
40     2015-02-10      25
30     2015-02-10      5
10     2015-03-10      15
10     2014-01-10      25
20     2014-02-10      35
50     2014-03-10      45
```

In Tableau I want a line graph to display 
(YTD Sum of Score)/Total number of IDs for a year.

```
For Jan 2015 - 10/4=2.5
For Feb 2015 - 55/4=13.75
For Jan 2014 - 60/3=20
```

The denominator should remain constant throughout the year and not change monthwise.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can achieve your desired result with two calculated fields. First, make a [Year] field with:

```
year([Date])
```

Then make a second calculated field as follows:

```
sum([Score])/sum({fixed [Year] : countd([Id])})
```

This will sum the score and divide by IDs for the given year. It uses [Level of Detail](http://www.tableau.com/LOD-expressions) calculation.